# Colour code files based on extension in linux

Tags: linux, bash, color-scheme

I was wondering if in linux there were a way to coulor files by extension, so that, for example a .py or a .C file would have a different color.

So far, all I managed to do is to change the colouring scheme in the ~/.bashrc file to distinguish directories, executables etc. but no way to colour code the files based on the extension.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ls` command uses the environment variable LS_COLORS to determine
       the colors in which the filenames are to be displayed.   This  environment variable is usually set by a command like

```
eval `dircolors some_path/dir_colors`
```

found  in a system default shell initialization file, like /etc/profile
       or /etc/csh.cshrc. Usually,  the  file  used
       here  is /etc/DIR_COLORS and can be overridden by a .dir_colors file in
       one's home directory.

You can find more information by typing in the terminal `man dir_colors`